# hector_mapping: base_link -> laser transform times out once

Tags: slam, navigation, hokuyo-node, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm setting up a hector_mapping node.
My simple launch file sets up a static base_link -> laser transform:

```
<node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">

    <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
    <param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />

</node>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 100" />
```

When I run it, I get the following error, but only once:

```
lookupTransform base_link to laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
```

Does that mean there is one lookupTransform call for which the tf wasn't set up, but then it found it?

Thanks in advance,

Ernest

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53611/hector_mapping:-base_link--%3E-laser-transform-times-out-once/) by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes that is what it means.

When you start everything tf information needs to be received by the tf listener first. Until some information has arrived that calls fails. If it only happens at the start it should be fine.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on 2013-01-29**:
Great - thank you.

**Comment by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on 2017-03-12**:
I am getting the same error.. What should I do?